# Email Signatures in AWS Pinpoint Templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

Is there any way to create reusable email signatures in AWS Pinpoint? I'm looking at the API reference and there doesn't seem to be any attributes for managing email signatures or embedding them in an email template.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/templates-template-name-email.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS support confirmed they do not have a feature supporting emails signature management. So the solution will be left up to you, either managing your templates dynamically or providing a template variable you manage for merging the signature